# php mysql query that removes friend request if the userid exits as a friend

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hi I have been working on a simple php mysql friends list backend. The friend and friends list and friends requests list for a user is generated from 1 table, friends. Below are the columns in the friends table:

```
id   user_id  friend_user_id    is_confirmed     date_created
```

`id` is the self explanatory `unique` `auto increment` `int` value.

`user_id` is the unique `ai` `int` value of the user who initially sent a friend request.

`friend_user_id` is the `unique` `ai` `int` value of the user receiving the friend request.

`is_confirmed` is a column that can only have 2 value 0 and 1. If `is_confirmed = 0`, then the friend request has not been accepted by the `user` with that `specified friend_user_id`, that the row only displays in the friend requests section. When the friend request is accepted `is_confirmed = 1` and the row should only display under the friends section.

For some reason, once the friend request is accepted, both the initial friend request and the new friend are both displaying. Apparently if you are already a friend there shouldn't be a friend request.

Below if my code for displaying friends and friend requests.

```
function displayFriends($userid){
    $result = query2("SELECT u.id, u.username
                      FROM users AS u
                      INNER JOIN friends AS f ON f.friend_user_id = u.id 
                       WHERE (f.user_id ='%s' AND f.is_confirmed=1)", $userid);

    if (!$result['error']) {
        print json_encode($result);
    } else {
         errorJson('no friends');
    }
}

function displayFriendRequests($userid){
    $result = query2("SELECT u.id, u.username
                      FROM users AS u
                      INNER JOIN friends AS f ON f.user_id = u.id
                      WHERE f.friend_user_id ='%s' AND f.is_confirmed=0", $userid);
    if (!$result['error']) {
        print json_encode($result);
    } else {    
        errorJson('no event data');
    }
}
```

What can I do to fix this issue?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry for the large amount of text.

Comment: What is `query2`? That looks terrifying.

Comment: think of it simply as "query" not query2 lol. I can post the code for the query function if you'd like. It simply lets me input php variables within the mysql query being used.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. Creating "helper" functions like that has the effect of hiding what are usually severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because how you're handling those values isn't obvious.

Comment: Do you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on your friends table to prevent duplicate records?

Comment: @tadman: I do not have a UNIQUE constraint. There is a check that is done on the php side that checks if a friend request has already been sent to a specific user, if so the request isn't sent. There are no duplicate friends or friend requests on the table.

Comment: You really do need a constraint or you will, eventually, get duplicate data and then who knows what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

If this is some sort of one-way vector, where A friends B but B must confirm A as a friend, then you'll have to insert pairs of entries, one confirmed, one unconfirmed, in the correct pairings. As with a lot of things that are directional, you can easily get your pairings confused, wiring things up backwards.

To display **pending friend requests** initiated by a given user:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username
  FROM friends
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id=friends.friend_user_id
  WHERE friends.user_id=? AND f.is_confirmed=0
```

To display **friends of** a particular user:

```
SELECT users.id, users.username
  FROM friends
  INNER JOIN users ON users.id=friends.user_id
  WHERE friends.friend_user_id=? AND f.is_confirmed=1
```

Here I'm presuming the initiator is `user_id` and the recipient is `friend_user_id`.

Comment: Now the only thing that is not making sense about these queries is that you are selecting data that comes from the users table, but you have FROM friends. Did you mean to type something like SELECT u.id FROM users as u? It is just not making sense to me that you are Selecting users.id, user.username FROM friends

Comment: I'm simply starting with the `friends` table, anchoring the query there, and then use `JOIN` to add `users` data. There's nothing in SQL that forces you to select columns from the first table you start with.